# Error installing npm dependencies: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ories":{},"dist":{"in'

Tags: angular, npm

I am getting Error while running `npm install`. The logs from debug.log are as follows:

```
2644 silly saveTree +-- webfontloader@1.6.28
2644 silly saveTree `-- zone.js@0.8.26
2645 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ories":{},"dist":{"in'
2645 verbose stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
2645 verbose stack     at parseJson (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\json-parse-better-errors\index.js:7:17)
2645 verbose stack     at consumeBody.call.then.buffer (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\body.js:96:50)
2645 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

angular version `6.1.10`

npm `6.4.1`

Node `10.10.0`

Windows 10

package.json dependencies:

```
"@angular/animations": "6.1.10",
"@angular/cli": "~6.2.4",
"@angular/common": "6.1.10",
"@angular/compiler": "6.1.10",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "6.1.10",
"@angular/core": "6.1.10",
"@angular/forms": "6.1.10",
"@angular/http": "6.1.10",
"@angular/platform-browser": "6.1.10",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.1.10",
"@angular/router": "6.1.10",
"jest": "23.5.0",
```

Any pointers to get this working is greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you add your full package.json file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cure for this is to get the npm-cache cleaned up:

1. I had to clean my npm cache, delete existing npm-cache directory
   from the `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming`.

   run
   `npm cache clean --force`
2. I also had to set up npm config to use `http` in stead of `https`.
3. Delete node_modules from the project directory.
4. Run `npm install` to install project dependencies.